# Canvas height not available in advanced parameters

Tags: parameters, facebook-apps

I've created a new app, and made a couple of adjustments in the parameters.
Now I'd like to change the height of the canvas, but when I go to Parameters > Advanced, I don't find anything related to the canvas.

If I remember well, it was there when I created the app. Could it be that I changed a parameter that makes this change now unavailable?

Thanks for your help!

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up your app as a canvas or page tab app (Meaning providing URLs for at least one of these), for the canvas-options to be available on the advanced-tab.